# Javascript Arrow calling a function from another with functionName() vs ()=>functionName

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Let's say you have a method/function which you did not want to call until runtime.

```
const someMethod = () => {
  document.getElementById("myField").value = "Hello";
}
```

What is the term for and what is the difference between how these are executed.

```
this.check(() => someMethod);
```

AND

```
this.check(someMethod())
```

Comment: There are plenty of resources on the Internet detailing functions in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: @MartinBean of course there are. I'm asking a very specific question in that I could not locate the answer.

Comment: This isn’t a programming problem, though. This is a question of general understanding. Take [the tour](/tour) for examples of the type of questions that should be asked on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're entirely different.

`this.check(() => someMethod);` will pass a callback which, when called (if ever), returns a function.

`this.check(someMethod())` will call `someMethod` *immediately*, then pass the result to the `this.check` method.

Another option not listed is `this.check(() => someMethod());`, which will call `someMethod` when the callback passed to `check` is called.

If the `this` context is something you're worried about, then:

```
this.check(someObj.someMethod)
```

will result in `someMethod`, when invoked, to be invoked with a `this` of *whatever the `check` method wants it to be*. It does *not* preserve the context of `someObj`. In contrast

```
this.check(() => someObj.someMethod())
```

will result in `someMethod` being invoked with a `this` of `someObj`, regardless of how `check` tries to call it.

So, usually, to be safe, you'll want `this.check(() => someObj.someMethod())` - or bind `someMethod` in advance, or declare `someMethod` with an arrow function instead of a `function`.

Answer (score 0):

Here: `this.check` receives a callback as its paramter which returns the `someMethod` function.

```
this.check(() => someMethod);
```

And in this case: `this.check` receives the value that `someMethod` returns as its parameter.

```
this.check(someMethod())
```